# SVN - Get all commit messages for a file?

Tags: svn, logging, shell

Is there a way to get a nice list of all commit messages sorted by file? Something like this (as you can see, I don't want the messages specific to a certain file, just show messages for the entire commit if the file was part of the commit, repeats ok):

```
-- index.php
    2010-01-02 03:04:05
      * added new paragraph
    2010-01-01 03:04:05
      * moved header out of index.php into header.php
      * header.php initial check-in
    2009-12-31 03:04:05
      * index.php initial check-in

-- header.php
    2010-01-03 03:04:05
      * added new meta tags
    2010-01-01 03:04:05
      * moved header out of index.php into header.php
      * header.php initial check-in
```

Additional information:

`svn log filename` does something similar, but I want it to do this:

1. get a list of files that have changed between yyyy-mm-dd (r2) and yyyy-mm-dd (r4)
   (i.e.

   ```
   svn log -q -v -r 2:4 > changedfiles.txt
   ```
2. strip extraneous crap from changedfiles.txt
3. svn log each file in that list, as in:

   ```
   svn log < changedfiles.txt >> combinedlog.txt
   ```

   (just pseudocode, i know svn log takes arguments not input, but can't be bothered to write it out)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`svn log filename` will show all commit messages associated with `filename`.  The output will look something like the following:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1206 | kalebp | 2010-03-10 16:48:12 -0800 (Wed, 10 Mar 2010) | 1 line

Introduce a TranslatorFacade. Make the jar runnable by default.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1085 | kalebp | 2010-03-02 17:10:28 -0800 (Wed, 04 Nov 2009) | 1 line

Annotation checker now supports complete definitions and named parameters
------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

If you don't want information prior to a branch or copy there is a `--stop-on-copy` option that you can add.  See `svn help log` for more information, such as how to specify date ranges, etc.

**EDIT:**

You can easily grab by a date range using `svn log -r{20100101}:{20100331}`.  I don't like the idea of calling log for changed files, so I'd recommend using the `-v` flag to get a list of files that changed in the commit.

Here's the process that I would use:

```
svn log -r{20100101}:{20100331} -v --xml | xsltproc formatter.xsl -
```

And here's formatter.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xsd"
        version="1.0"
        >

<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />

<xsl:key name="paths-key" match="/log/logentry/paths" use="path" />

<xsl:template match="log/logentry">
        <xsl:for-each select="paths/path[count(. | key('paths-key', paths/path)[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:sort select="text()"/>
                -- <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                <xsl:for-each select="key('paths-key', .)/preceding-sibling::date">
                        <xsl:sort select="translate(text(), '-:.T','')"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="selectedDate" select="text()"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="translate($selectedDate, 'T', ' ')"/><xsl:text>
                        </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::msg">
                                * <xsl:variable name="msg" select="text()"/>
                                <xsl:variable name="date" select="preceding-sibling::date/text()"/>
                                <xsl:if test="$selectedDate = $date">
                                        <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$msg"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

I imagine `svn log --xml` and some sort of command-line XPath or XSLT is going to be your best bet.

Comment: XPath is for accessing nodes, but the XSLT is a good idea, so I've included such a solution in my post.  XQuery would also work. :).

Answer (score 1):

With the command `svn log`

Comment: I would have to script and parse it (svn list gets everything, don't want that) to get a list of changed files >> changedfiles.txt, and then run svn log on the contents of changedfiles.txt in order to get a list like the one I wanted. I want to know if there's a better way.

Comment: You could also do svn log -v to get the full logs and aggegrate the comments per file.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something more than just SVN to accomplish this programmatically. If .Net is not a problem, I recommend [SharpSVn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/). The code below should get you somewhat started.

```
var la = new SvnLogArgs { Start = 16077, End = 17445  };
Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> list;
client.GetLog(new Uri(_respositoryPath), la, out list);

foreach (SvnLogEventArgs a in list)
{
    // ...jazz
}
```